# Como eu posso gravar informações com Arduino?

Tags: arduino

Estamos desenvolvendo um sistema de leitura para verificar parâmetros de pulsos elétricos que são medidos direto da rede elétrica de um residencia, e para que isso ocorra  precisamos ler e arquivar esses parâmetros durante um mês.
 Seria possível fazer isso com o Arduíno(a parte de leitura de dados já esta ok)? Qual a forma de armazenagem ideal?

Comment: atualizei a resposta com mais algumas informações. Podem ser úteis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sim, é possível.

Existem três maneiras bem interessantes de gravar as informações geradas pelo Arduino.

## Computador (via Serial RS-232 ou Ethernet)

Essa é a maneira mais básica. Você liga o Arduino em um computador (via Serial RS-232) e faz um programa (script simples) que se conecta ao Arduino e grava as informações num arquivo texto. Linguagens sugeridas para isso: Processing, Python ou Groovy.

## Cartão SD

Você consegue armazenar informações no Arduino utilizando um cartão SD. Existem módulos, shields e até mesmo Arduinos que já vem com uma entrada para um cartão SD. Além disso, as bibliotecas existentes para gravação e leitura são bem simples de serem utilizadas.

[Notas sobre o uso de SD com Arduino](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SDCardNotes)

## ScadaBR (ModBus)

Uma outra opção, bem interessante é utilizar o ScadaBR. O ScadaBR é uma aplicação Java WEB (para ser executada no Tomcat). Essa aplicação consegue interpretar vários protocolos, sendo um deles chamado ModBus (via Serial RS-232 ou RS-485 ou via Ethernet). Assim, você utiliza uma biblioteca ModBus no Arduino, liga o seu Arduino via Serial no Computador com ScadaBR e configura o ScadaBR para receber informações do Arduino. A grande vantagem dessa abordagem é que o ScadaBR pode ser utilizado para vários Arduinos e para logar os mais diferentes tipos de informação. O céu é o limite.

O ScadaBR utiliza o banco de dados Derby (Apache) e nele ficam registrados as informações. É bem simples obter um período de tempo. Tem inclusive gráficos prontos.

Para você ter uma ideia do poder da combinação do Arduino + ScadaBR, na empresa que trabalho a equipe de manutenção desenvolveu uma solução com essa combinação que permite religar uma sub-estação elétrica utilizando o ScadaBR.

## Resumo

Se o seu Arduino pode executar perto de um computador e o problema que você deseja resolver é pontual, vai na opção Computador via Serial. Você vai resolver isso bem rápido.

Se o seu Arduino deve rodar longe de um computador e você não tem tempo para conectá-lo via Ethernet ou RS-485, então vai pela opção Cartão SD.

Se você quer uma solução para atender vários Arduinos e outros tipos de dispostivos que conversam ModBus, vai pelo ScadaBR.

Comment: @cardoni muito obrigado cara!! Ajudou muito vou falar com a equipe sobre as suas  importantes soluções!!