# Internet das coisas e acesso remoto

Tags: arduino

Tenho um protótipo de automação residencial de lâmpadas usando Arduino, caso eu deseje controlar os meus sensores fora da rede local qual a **solução adequada** hoje em dia? Há alguma outra opção além das listadas? 
É claro que isso depende de vários fatores do projeto mas pergunto profissionalmente quais são mais utilizadas, como é algo novo e as referências são poucas.

1) Projetos amadores geralmente utilizam a própria rede, pelo o que eu entendi configuram o IP público e o no-ip do modem para acessar remotamente. Porém não há uma implicação em questão da segurança da minha rede? Já que poderei acessá-la remotamente

Referências
http://www.noip.com/pt-BR/remote-access

http://labdegaragem.com/forum/topics/como-configurar-no-ip-no-modem-tchinicolor-5130v2

2) AWS IoT, Azure IoT, Google Cloud etc.

3) Ter um banco de dados hospedado remotamente o qual armazena o status do meu sensor. O meu Arduino e minha aplicação irão verificar, atualizar de acordo com o status e alterar o banco. Porém não tenho nenhuma necessidade de ficar guardando registros de sensores, seria apenas um campo "status" com opção on/off e não seria algo muito complexo para realizar uma coisa tão simples?

Comment: É interessante o uso do  *AWS IoT* para gerenciar os dispositivos, me parece uma tecnologia que lhe pouparia muito trabalho caso no futuro você desejaria expandir seu projeto.

Comment: Mas, deve haver outras soluções que se adapte melhor a sua necessidade, como eu não tenho conhecimento nesta área fica difícil eu apontar um caminho, porem, eu preferia ver uma resposta de alguém da comunidade, porque esta é uma ótima questão (+1).

Comment: Estou sem tempo para montar uma resposta agora, mas na empresa aonde trabalho fizemos a seguinte combinação: ScadaBR para armazenar os dados dos sensores (aqui precisamos disso). Além disso, para uma pessoa específica, liberamos o ScadaBR na VPN da empresa. Essa pessoa consegue ligar e desligar uma subestação de energia elétrica. Enfim, o banco de dados é Interno, a Aplicação é Interna e o acesso externo só ocorre via VPN.

Comment: Ta aí um exemplo real da completa falta de preocupação de segurança com automações residenciais ou comerciais: no caso aqui foi em um Hotel na Inglaterra: https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/40505.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) Projetos amadores geralmente utilizam a própria rede, pelo o que eu
>   entendi configuram o IP público e o no-ip do modem para acessar
>   remotamente. Porém não há uma implicação em questão da segurança da
>   minha rede? Já que poderei acessá-la remotamente

O fato de utilizar um serviço de IP Dinâmico como no-ip não implica em vulnerabilidade. Serviços como no-ip apenas provêm uma maneira de atualizar o DNS com o IP dinâmico cedido pelo provedor. É preciso apenas uma configuração ou script no roteador que atualize, periodicamente, o IP atual cedido pelo provedor para o serviço de DNS dinâmico. Lembre-se que o roteador é sempre alcançável via IP, mesmo sem DNS dinâmico. Enfim, um nome não é mais seguro do que um número.

O que gera problemas de vulnerabilidade são roteadores mal configurados e o uso indiscriminado de certas funcionalidades, como redirecionamento de portas. Não se assuste se houver várias empresas que redirecionam as portas de um banco de dados como MySQL, SQL Server. Com isso, qualquer um consegue pelo menos tentar conectar nesses bancos de dados. Claro, é preciso fazer uma autenticação proprietária do próprio banco, mas só o fato de expor o banco de dados dessa maneira já é um furo de segurança gigantesco.

As alternativas para acesso remoto seguro são várias. Umas delas é permitir o acesso à rede interna apenas por VPN, uma outra é fazer um túnel SSH. Em ambas as duas, o ideal é que os serviços de VPN e SSH estejam rodando, preferencialmente, no roteador. Para isso, é necessário um roteador que rode Linux. Existe uma distribuição Linux chamada OpenWRT que roda em vários roteadores (eu tenho o [TP-LINK N750](http://www.tp-link.com.br/products/details/cat-9_TL-WDR4300.html)). A partir do momento que você tem um Linux rodando em seu roteador, as possibilidades aumentam exponencialmente. É possível, por exemplo, instalar o [OpenVPN](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/downloads.html) e fazer um servidor VPN para que você conecte em sua rede interna de forma segura (existe OpenVPN para o Windows, você pode conectar a partir do Windows no seu roteador Linux). Se o caso for apenas um redirecionamento de porta, faça um Túnel SSH. Entretanto, nesse caso, não sei se o cliente poderia ser Windows (deve existir).

Para finalizar, eu não afirmaria que utilizar a própria rede configura um projeto amador. Se você souber o que está fazendo, seu projeto pode ser tão profissional em questão de segurança, comparado a uma grande empresa.

> 2) AWS IoT, Azure IoT, Google Cloud etc.

Preciso verificar para responder com mais embasamento.

> 3) Ter um banco de dados hospedado remotamente o qual armazena o
>   status do meu sensor. O meu Arduino e minha aplicação irão verificar,
>   atualizar de acordo com o status e alterar o banco. Porém não tenho
>   nenhuma necessidade de ficar guardando registros de sensores, seria
>   apenas um campo "status" com opção on/off e não seria algo muito
>   complexo para realizar uma coisa tão simples?

A vantagem de um mundo conectado é que existem muitas possibilidades de fazer a mesma coisa. A ideia de um banco de dados remoto é interessante e facilmente implementada. Poderia, inclusive, ser feita junto com uma App WEB no estilo WebService. Assim, você poderia implementar no Arduino algo que acesse esse WebService e obtém/atualiza alguma informação remotamente. O problema desse tipo de abordagem é segurança. Fica complicado fazer o Arduino autenticar de uma maneira mais segura (HTTPS), devido a sua limitação de processamento/memória. Provavelmente, daria pra usar apenas a autentição HTTP básica. Entretanto, suspeito que o AWS IoT substitui isso de uma maneira mais direcionada para a Internet das Coisas.

Suas preocupações são extremamente relevantes e creio que muita gente que está trabalhando com automação residencial não entende esses conceitos de segurança. Isso implica, infelizmente, em casas facilmente hackeadas.

**Uma alternativa *in-house***

Uma outra opção é construir uma aplicação WebService que rodaria dentro da residência. Esta aplicação seria acessada pelos Arduinos internos com autenticação básica HTTP. Os Arduinos fariam atualização dos dados dos sensores nessa aplicação. Essa mesma aplicação estaria exposta na Internet via HTTPS, sendo possível acessar a residência de maneira segura, inclusive atuando (desligando e ligando coisas). Obviamente, o banco de dados, nesse caso, ficaria dentro de casa também. Um serviço como no-ip se torna essencial nesse contexto.

O [ScadaBR](http://www.scadabr.com.br/) é uma excelente alternativa nesse contexto (ele inclusive funciona como WebService também). Ele "conversa" vários protocolos, incluindo o famoso ModBus. Existe biblioteca ModBus para o Arduino que funciona muito bem. Tanto a versão Serial, quanto a versão Ethernet. Uma resposta relacionada: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100148/3084

Como eu disse em meu comentário, o cenário da empresa que trabalho é: ScadaBR + Arduino + Dispositivo proprietário (que fala ModBus) e juntos monitoram + comandam (ligando e desligando) uma subestação de energia. O ScadaBR é acessível internamente na empresa via HTTPS e possui autenticação própria. Ele não está disponível para acesso externo, com exceção de uma pessoa específica que, via VPN (OpenVPN), consegue religar a subestação remotamente quando há uma queda de energia.